# AngularJs: how http get data.column variable

Tags: angularjs, http, variables, get, angularjs-scope

Hi I want to combine the singleton data coming with http get with the model from the selection box.

```
$scope.ShowResult = function() {
  $http.get('http://otm.dev/carPrice?modelId=' + $scope.model_id).success(function(data) {

    var result = $filter('filter')(data, {
      kaskobedel_marka_id: $scope.model_id
    })[0];

    $scope.name = result.a;

  });
};
```

with

```
<select class="form-control" name="price" ng-model="year" ng-click="ShowResult()">
  <option value="">Select Year</option>
  <option value="a">2003</option>
  <option value="b">2004</option>
  <option value="c">2005</option>
  <option value="d">2006</option>
  <option value="e">2007</option>
  <option value="f">2008</option>
  <option value="g">2009</option>
  <option value="h">2010</option>
  <option value="i">2011</option>
  <option value="j">2012</option>
  <option value="k">2013</option>
  <option value="l">2014</option>
  <option value="m">2015</option>
  <option value="n">2016</option>
  <option value="o">2017</option>
</select>
```

The database is stored in years a, b, c
That is, a = 2003, b = 2004, c = 2005. I need to merge the fetched data with the value from the selection box and get the data for that column. Please help me in my different combinations.

[Here Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tolgaarslan/stowtznz/)

Comment: look at ng-options usage

Comment: your fiddle is not correct, please set it up with angular

Comment: How can I use the ng-options in this way according to the table according to the incoming data.
http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bPrBOrQqUO?indent=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I solved it like this.

```
    $scope.getYear = function (model) {
    $http.get('http://otm.dev/carPrice?modelId='+$scope.model_id)
        .success(function(resp) {
            var result = $filter('filter')(resp, {kaskobedel_marka_id:$scope.model_id})[0];
            $scope.name = result[model];
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$scope.getData = function(){
   $http.get('http://otm.dev/carPrice?modelId='+$scope.model_id).success(function(data) {
       var result = $filter('filter')(data, {kaskobedel_marka_id:$scope.model_id})[0];
       $scope.data = result;
        }
    });
}
$scope.getData();
$scope.ShowResult = function () {
    $scope.name = $scope.data[$scope.year];
};
```